# Copy PivotTable range from one worksheet to another worksheet. Code is copying active sheet data instead

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PivotTable on worksheet (inventorySheet) and I want to copy the PivotTable data, which starts on cells P5 and Q5. I have a macro button I press on another worksheet (the sheet i want the data to be pasted on), but my code is copying data from the active worksheet instead of from inventorySheet.

I'm new to coding, but shouldn't my code Range("P5:Q5", Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy copy data from inventorySheet since it's within the With statement?

```
With inventorySheet
    .PivotTables("inventoryPivot").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("inventoryPivot").PivotFields("Type"). _
        CurrentPage = "REGIONAL"
    Range("P5:Q5", Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.Range("P5:Q5", .Range("P5:Q5").End(xlDown)).Copy`  Without the `.` it's not scoped to the With block

Comment: Code stops on that line with run-time error with the . added in front of range, was wondering it was doing that

Comment: What's the error?  FYI instead of Range...End you can refer directly to the part(s) of the PT which you want to copy: that is the safer approach  See https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Didn't know PT had specific references, that's good to know, thanks! How can I copy just the data portion? Not the headers but all the data below. Essentially the DataBodyRange but with the column to the left highlighted as well.

Comment: Hi Tim, been working on this sparingly. I understand now why `.` is needed in front of both ranges. Believe it's so it calls from the inventorySheet. Otherwise without the `.`, even though it's within the With statement, it calls from the active sheet. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - code inside the `With` block is only scoped to the "With object" if you add the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim rngCopy As range
With inventorySheet.PivotTables("inventoryPivot")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFields("Type").CurrentPage = "REGIONAL"
    'data body range plus one column to the left...
    With .DataBodyRange
        Set rngCopy = .Offset(0, -1).Resize( , .Columns.Count +1)
    End with
    rngCopy.Copy
End With
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked. Could you explain the set rngCopy part? i under stand the data range body is the right column (Q column), so we offset one column to the left (P column), but what is the resize part?

Comment: We're "moving" the range corresponding to `DataBodyRange` over, by one column to the left, so that would then leave the right-most column not included.  Resizing by one column expands the range at the right-hand edge, to re-include that column.

Comment: Instead of moving the `DataBodyRange` to the left, can't we just resize the `DataBodyRange` to include the column to the left? `DataBodyRange` already selects the correct data, why move it over, then resize back?

Comment: You can only resize a range by growing/shrinking the right and bottom borders...

Comment: Got it. Awesome, thanks for helping with the learning process. Much appreciated Tim!

Comment: Another question - how come we need to create another With statement and set rngCopy? I tried to put this into a single line, but it didn't work. 

`.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1).Copy`.

When I included the With statement it seems to work. 
`With .DataBodyRange
        .Offset(0, -1).Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1).Copy
    End With`

Is there a need for the Set rngCopy? Seems to work without it. Also, how come we use `.Columns.Count + 1`  this also works `Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Copy`. Thanks Tim!

Comment: If you don't use the `With` then you need to prepend each leading period with `.DataBodyRange` so `Set rngCopy = .DataBodyRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize( , .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count +1)`  As previously - check the *whole line of code*

Comment: I'll have to look into that more. I don't fully understand the grammar of VBA so to speak. Also, I was trying to understand why you wrote `.Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)` instead of `.Resize(,2)`. Ty!

Comment: It's always a good idea to minimize the number of "magic numbers" in your code - "2" is a fixed value and may break if your pivot table changes, whereas `.Columns.Count + 1` will adapt to any changes in `DataBodyRange`